# How to access the emergency room interface for D-Link DIR-600 B2 with firmware v.2.15?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, firmware

I have a D-Link DIR-600 B2 router with firmware v.2.15 and I want to install the DD-WRT firmware ([described here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DIR-600)) to enable the repeater mode.

The problem is, every time I try to upload the DD-WRT firmware using the standard admin page, I receive the "Invalid image" error message, and I can't proceed.

So I tried using the emergency room page, by turning the device on holding the reset button. I followed these instructions:

> Setup your PC with static IP on 192.168.0.0 subnet.
>
> Open your web browser and get it ready to connect to 192.168.0.1.
>
> Press and HOLD the reset button on the router and connect power. Hold the reset button for about 3~5 seconds, then release.
>
> Connect the browser to http://192.168.0.1/ . The Emergency Room Updating Firmware screen should display.

I changed my machine IP to static 192.168.0.2, and I can't connect to the router at 192.168.0.1. I tried to scan for other IPs, and could not find any other ones:

> nmap -PR -sP 192.168.0.1/24
>
> Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.00 seconds

The firmware cloud be blocking the emergency room interface, but I can't downgrade it using the standard admin page.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: What browser are you using? Try using Mozilla. I had attempted DD-WRT quite sometime back on my DIR615. I do remember facing some similar issue but not exactly the same, and in my case I tried with different browsers and with Mozilla it worked.  While your situation may be different, just give a try with different browsers!!

Comment: @pat2015 I tried with both Firefox and Chrome, from different machines with different OSes (Windows 8 and Linux Ubuntu 14.04), no luck.